# How can I have different configuration in different workspaces in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, workspace

Is it possible at all to have different configurations in different workspaces in Ubuntu, like different files and shortcuts, wallpaper, panels, panel status (hidden/unhidden), etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have separate users for this?

Comment: Not really what I wanted. Apparently it's not possible from what I've collected so far. Hope some variations of these features will be incorporated into Ubuntu in the coming years, which would be really neat.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple: **No**.
I looked into this matter as well about half a year ago, and my conclusion was that there was no user-friendly way to do this. No way to do it that is worth the effort anyway.
The thing that comes closest to what you want is *Wallpapoz*. It lets you have a slideshow as your wallpaper, and as a little extra **it allows you to have different wallpapers on your workspaces** (it will just change the wallpaper whenever you switch workspaces).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion though the wallpaper is the least of the features I wanted. I guess we'll just have to wait for something similar to be available.